# Firebase Scheduled Function to read Data from Firestore and then do some updaates

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble writing a scheduled function to read data from firestore. The function is successfully running every 1 minute but now the problem is reading the data from firestore. I am using async-await because I  want to loop through the data after the read then do then so some update. Kindly help I am using firebase functions for the first time.
Below is my function. I keep getting this error **cannot read property map of undefined**

```
exports.checkDefaultedPledges = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 minutes").onRun( async 
(context) => {
  console.log("This will be run every 2 minutes!");
  const time = new Date().getTime();
  const snapshot = db.collection("pledges").get();
  const res = await snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
  console.log(res);

  return null;
});
```

Is it possible for me to write this function without using the .then()?

Comment: "Is it possible for me to write this function without using the .then()?" => Yes. What exactly do you want to update (which documents and with which data? all the docs from the snapshot? etc..)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec before even the update. The problem I am having is that no data is being returned when reading the data. I get this error cannot read the property map of undefined.

Comment: You need to do `const snapshot = await db.collection("pledges").get();`, since `get()` is asynchronous. And you should not use `await` in `const res = await snapshot.docs.map()` since maps is a simple property (no asynchronicity here).

Comment: Typo in above comment. Should read: "since `docs` is a simple property (no asynchronicity here)"

Comment: Thank you @RenaudTarnec. It worked. I now understand what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I am having is that no data is being returned when reading
> the data.

You need to use `await` when calling `get()`, since it is an asynchronous method.

On the other hand, you should not use `await` in `const res = await snapshot.docs.map()` since `docs` is a simple property (no asynchronicity here).

---

If you want to update all the docs in the `pledges` collection, you can use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) as follows:

```
exports.checkDefaultedPledges = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {

    const time = new Date().getTime();
    const snapshot = await db.collection("pledges").get();

    const batch = db.batch();

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        batch.update(doc.ref, { "updateTime": time });
    })

    return batch.commit();
});
```

Note that a batched write can contain up to 500 operations: so if you know your collection has/will have more than 500 docs, you should use `Promise.all()` as follows:

```
exports.checkDefaultedPledges = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {

    const time = new Date().getTime();
    const snapshot = await db.collection("pledges").get();

    const promisesArray = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({ "updateTime": time }));

    return Promise.all(promisesArray);
});
```

---

**Side note:**

It is a best practice to use [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#servertimestamp) instead of using the JS `Date()`, especially when you are writing to Firestore from a client app. `serverTimestamp` "returns a sentinel used with `set()` or `update()` to include a **server-generated timestamp** in the written data".

Since a Cloud Function is executed by a server, it is not a must, but you could adapt your code as follows:

```
const time = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```